# How do you design against an earthquake?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

**How do you design against an earthquake?** 
Do one initially consider earthquake in early design stages or is earthquake mitigation considered later in the design stage after conceptual stage?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the above-mentioned approach?

I am unable to find enough material online on this topic can someone guide me on this so that I can further my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general shape of the building will affect earthquake resistance. I think L-shaped buildings are quite bad. You also need to know whether the soil is capable of supporting a heavy, tall building during an earthquake. If you want to keep the cost under control, better make a decision early in the design process on where to put supporting walls and structures so that you get sufficient resistance for a minimum amount of material.

Comment: Thanks, Can you recommend me any suggested readings? I searched The Internet could not find anything that was so specific to my question.

Comment: No specific sources - My job involves the engineering of big systems, but not so much buildings. If you google for "earthquake resistant", "earthquake proof", "seismic retrofit", you'll find plenty of examples of techniques and it will be obvious that many of those techniques need to be designed into the building from an early stage.